# How do I get the value of a cell and not the keyvalue of a row in devexpress gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

Trying to bind some other value then "Container.KeyValue" to my linked row. Not sure how to get the value from the "TidrapportId" cell to accompany the clickElement.

When I click the Field Value in "Tid" I want to create a link using the value from "TidrapportId".

```
<Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="AnvId" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false">
        <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Ansvarig" ReadOnly="True" Width="200px" />
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Namn" ReadOnly="True" Width="200px" />
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Vecka" VisibleIndex="3">
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="VeckoDatum" VisibleIndex="4" Width="200px" Visible="false">
    </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Tid" VisibleIndex="5" ReadOnly="True">
        <DataItemTemplate>
            <a id="clickElement" target="_blank" href="Tidrapport.aspx?id=<%# Container.KeyValue%>"><%# Eval("Tid").ToString()%></a>
        </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="OTid" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="6" Visible="false">
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="KvalTid" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="7" Visible="false">
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="TidrapportId" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="8" Visible="True">
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can realize method in codebehind of the page

```
    protected string GetUrl(GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer container)
    {
        if (container != null)
        {
            var tdi = _gridView.GetRowValues(container.VisibleIndex, "Tdi");
            return String.Format("Tidrapport.aspx?id=?{0}{1}", container.KeyValue, tdi);
        }

        return "Tidrapport.aspx";
    }
```

and use it in your page layout

```
<dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn FieldName="Tid" >
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="ASPxHyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# GetUrl(Container) %>" />
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataHyperLinkColumn>
```